# How to define the Artifact Registry repository to publish to in the init file?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, google-artifact-registry

I am using Gradle to deploy artifacts to Google's Artifact Registry.

Normally i would specify the repository I want to deploy the built artifact to in the "publishing" section of the `build.gradle` file - instead of doing it like that, I wanted to define the repository in a `init.gradle` file which is to be injected later in the CI-process, so that the URL of the Artifact Registry wouldn't end up in the Git repository.

I figured out a way to do this would be like that:

```
allprojects{  
    buildscript {
        repositories {
            maven {
                url "artifactregistry://random-location.pkg.dev/project-name/repository-name"
            }
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "artifactregistry://random-location.pkg.dev/project-name/repository-name"
        }
    }
}
```

But since I need the Artifact Registry Gradle plugin, I get the error that `artifactregistry` is not a supported protocol.

```
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Not a supported repository protocol 'artifactregistry': valid protocols are [file, http, https, gcs, s3, sftp]
```

[The docs state that](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/java/authentication#auth-helper) to use the plugin in `init.gradle`, the following needs to be inserted:

```
initscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.com.google.cloud.artifactregistry:artifactregistry-gradle-plugin:2.1.1"
  }
}
apply plugin: com.google.cloud.artifactregistry.gradle.plugin.ArtifactRegistryGradlePlugin
```

But I can't seem to make it work. I must have tried any possible combination of the two snippets, but I'm at the end of my knowledge.

If anyone could tell me how to arrange those two snippets so that I can specify the repository to publish to in the `init.gradle` file (or maybe there's a totally different way to do it), that would be extremely helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I found a way to make it work.

Instead of specifying the publishing repository, I just defined a variable  in the `init.gradle` file:

```
allprojects {
    ext.repositoryURL = "artifactregistry://random-location.pkg.dev/project-name/repository-name"
}
```

Which I then later used in the build script:

```
publishing {
    ...
    repositories {
        maven {
            url repositoryURL
        }
    }
}
```

This way I can still inject the `init.gradle` file later in order to specify the registry URL.