# Using GCP Artifact Registry to store NPM dependencies

Tags: npm, google-artifact-registry

Would like to use GCP Artifact Registry to be the source of truth for NPM packages to make sure developers are bringing in packages they have gone through licensing, vulnerability, and even potentially overriding them with a patched version

Google gives a few scenarios and use cases; but no real examples on how they suggesting doing this

> Store dependencies in a private registry
>
> Artifact Registry provides the convenience of installation from a public repository as well as control over your dependencies.

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/dependencies#approaches

> Explicitly mirror the third-party dependencies you need into your private repository, either manually or with a pull-through proxy

https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/dependencies#public-dependencies

The guide shows how to upload your package, but doesn't really give a good way to bulk import a bunch of dependencies that aren't yours; it would be even cool to see if a pull-through proxy is possible.

Comment: There's a quickstart [guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/nodejs/quickstart) that is available that you can also check.

Comment: @RJC if i'm not mistaken, that doesn't go over how to upload things like express or dependencies, just your actual project. I'm looking to store our organization's dependencies there in case NPM goes down and have stricter requirements of what can be brought in

Comment: Found this [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-registry-mirror) that you can check if this would work on your end. Additionally, verify if this StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68679097/16531380) would help you in determining what's the best course of action you can take. Lastly, check this documentation from the npm Documentations about [creating and publishing scoped public packages](https://docs.npmjs.com/creating-and-publishing-scoped-public-packages).