# Error installing executable npm package from GCP Artifact Registry

Tags: node.js, npm, google-cloud-platform, command-line-interface, google-artifact-registry

I have created a npm CLI project to generate projects with a specific template. I have tested it in my local environment by installing it using "npm install -g", and the command works correctly.

Then, I tried to publish it to a GCP Artifact Registry. After running the "npm pack" command, it generated a package with the files from my project, but the "node_modules" folder was missing. I published it, and everything seemed fine until I attempted to install the command globally by downloading it from GCP.

The command to install was:

```bash
npm install -g @mycompany/my-cli@1.0.0 --registry=https://us-central1-npm.pkg.dev/mygcpproject/myrepository/
```

I received the error message:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://us-central1-npm.pkg.dev/mygcpproject/myrepository/await-to-js - Requested entity was not found.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'await-to-js@^3.0.0' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-05-17T23_03_26_457Z-debug-0.log
```

> This is my first dependency en my project

What I understand is that when I upload this package to GCP, it does so without its dependencies. When I try to install it from GCP, the error occurs because the required dependencies are not available in my GCP Artifact Registry. I have tried uploading the dependencies manually to the GCP Artifact Registry, which partially solves the issue. However, there are too many dependencies to upload manually to GCP.

How can I publish this package so that other users can download and install it?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid npm ERR! 404 you may check with the below suggestions:

1. The latest version of `npm` is [7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/latest-version), Make sure you are using the latest version of `npm` and `nodejs`. If not please try to upgrade it by using the command: `npm install latest-version`.
2. Also make sure setting the .npmrc-file in the root of your project (or higher in the directory-tree) with:  `npm config set registry <registry url>`
3. Also try running the command `npm cache clean -f` which is an important part of the NPM package manager that helps speed up installation processes,  fix corrupted libraries and keeps track of what packages are installed on your machine.

Also have a look at this Stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71666253/18265702) which might be helpful.

Comment: I have those versions:
- node v16.14.2
- npm 9.6.7

I cleaned the cache and I got the same error, I think it is because dependences are not in my artifact registry, when I upload some of those I dont have the error for that, but the other dependences are necessaries.

Comment: Can you check with this Stackoverflow [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70857202/18265702)

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by making a script that automates the publication of all the dependencies of my project, since when trying to install the package it asks for all dependencies from the private repository.